# Understanding Spark Version

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

When i give `pyspark` in shell it displays spark version as `version 1.6.0` in console.

But when i give `spark2-submit --version` it says `version 2.2.0.cloudera2`.

I want to understand the difference between them and what is the actual version on which pyspark runs? Whenever is run a `py` script, I use `spark2-submit script.py`.

Comment: pyspark is an API developed in python for spark programming and writing spark applications in Python style, but underlying execution engine is spark.

Comment: What version of Cloudera CDH are you running?  My assumption is that there should also be a 'spark-submit' which should show the version as 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I give `pyspark2` it shows version 2.2.0. This matches with `spark2-submit --version`.

Answer (score 2):

Before executing Pyspark, try setting your spark version environment variable. Try to run this command below on your terminal :

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 pyspark
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't answer my question. When i enter into pyspark through shell it shows version 1.6. in console. But when i specifically check version with spark2-submit --version it says version 2.2. My question is why is the difference and which version actually is used when i run a script in pyspark?

Comment: You have two Spark versions on your machine. So by default, it will use spark 1.6 for pyspark unless you set SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 or call directly pyspark2